# Python: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,150) (2,150)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have the following program in python code but when I run it, throws the next error `"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,150) (2,150)" in line 37`, but I do not know what i need to do, How can it be solved?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1]])

B = np.array([[0.5, 0],
              [0, 0.5],
              [1, 0],
              [0, 1]])

H = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0]])

Q = np.array([[0.001, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0.001, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0.001, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0.001]])

R = np.array([[0.01, 0],
              [0, 0.01]])

x0 = np.array([[0],
               [0],
               [30],
               [40]])

P0 = np.eye(4)

dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 1.5, dt)

np.random.seed(0)
m_noise = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], R, len(t)).T
z = H @ (np.tile(x0, (1, len(t))) + m_noise)
```

i imagined that the array is different shape than the others array